# Ibatis - QueryforList

Tags: ibatis

Hi 
This might be basic question but I am new to Ibatis.
queryForList will return list of which objects? Generally for queryForObject we define a resultMap but no such map is defined for queryForList.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You just define a resultMap for query regardles of how many rows it is supposed to return. If you call queryforObject() then iBatis will assume that query schould return just one row. If I remember correctly it will throw exception if it returns more rows. If you call queryForList() then iBatis will assume query can return more than one row. In both scenarios for every row returned iBatis will do transformation based on resultMap, so you can think about resultMap as a recipe how to convert a single row into a single object.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following configuration in your mapping XML:

```
<select id="getFoo" resultClass="java.util.HashMap">
  select acctNbr, name, address
  from addressfile
  order by name
</select>
```

Then you can use queryForList to retrieve the result set in List form and iterate through its entries, like this:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> results = (List<Map<String,Object>>) sqlMap.queryForList("getFoo");
for (Map<String,Object> entry : results) {
  String acctNbr = entry.get("acctNbr");
  String name = entry.get("name");
  String address = entry.get("address");
  System.out.println(acctNbr + " : " + name + " : " + address + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

queryForList is also can use resultMap as List's item.
we assume that you have the following sql-map file.

```
<resultMap class="me.skpark.bean.CustomBean" id="custombean">
    <result property="v1" column="VALUE1" />
    <result property="v2" column="VALUE2" />
    <result property="v3" column="VALUE3" />
</resultMap>

<select id="select2" parameterClass="java.util.HashMap" resultMap="custombean" >
    select VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3from system_control_m
</select>
```

you can use List as receive data.

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("name", "park");
List<CustomBean> list = sqlMap.queryForList("select2", params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep that's right iBatis will throw an exception if more than one record is found when `queryForObject()` used.

If your using queryForList you can define a resultMap and I would rather define my resultMap with the returned class type and do the property to column mapping there. I think this looks more clean (looking at your DAO class it is easy to read and abstracted) and better abstracted. However this is my opinion.

```
<resultMap id="accountsResult" class="xx.co.xx.AccountsDTO">
    <result property="id" column="id" jdbcType="NUMERIC" javaType="java.lang.Long"/>
    <result property="name" column="name" jdbcType="NUMERIC" javaType="java.lang.Long"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="retrieveAccounts" resultMap="accountsResult">
    SELECT
    acounts.id,
    accounts.name
    FROM accounts
</select>
```

queryForList("retrieveAccounts");